# Automatically backlink org-mode links

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, org-mode

I'd really like to have the ability to automatically create backlinks to org-mode links.

What I mean is:

I have two files `a.org` and `b.org`. Inside `a.org` in heading Links I insert an org-link (with a new function org-link-with-backlink) to `b.org`. I'd like this to happen automatically: `b.org` is opened (if not open already) and inside its Links heading a link to `a.org` is created (if Links doesn't exist yet, create it by say prepending the file).

Thank you very much!

PS [optional]: I intend to use it in conjunction with [org-wiki](https://github.com/caiorss/org-wiki), to the solution could use the wiki style links as an alternative.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: It was fairly clear before @user673592 edited the question,  but the editing took out a significant chunk of the question, making it meaningless.

Comment: I suggested an edit to but the chunk back in assuming it was removed unintentionally.

Comment: Thank you, must have accidentaly wiped it before saving...